# Compile error: with request not something structure or union error

Tags: c

In this program, I am trying to create a struct, and then initialise a array with that struct type, put name and ages into the array, and print out the results. However, when I compile the file, it says that "names" and ages" are not something structure or union. Can anyone spot my errors please. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* these arrays are just used to give the parameters to 'insert',
   to create the 'people' array */
char *names[7]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
          "Harriet"};
int ages[7]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};


/* declare your struct for a person here */
typedef struct{
  char *names;
  int ages; 
}  person;

static void insert (person **p, char *s, int n) {

   *p = malloc(sizeof(person));

  static int nextfreeplace = 0;

  /* put name and age into the next free place in the array parameter here */
    (*p)->names=s;
    (*p)->ages=n;

  /* modify nextfreeplace here */
  nextfreeplace++;
  }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  /* declare the people array here */
   person *p[7];

   //insert the members and age into the unusage array. 
  for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
    insert (&p[i], names[i], ages[i]);
    p[i]= p[i+1];
  }

  /* print the people array here*/
  for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
    printf("name: %s, age:%i\n", p[i].names, p[i].ages);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

you declare `p` as an array of pointer to structure. On printf line, you dereference once `p` with `p[i]`, but p is still a pointer to a structure, you want to access its fields with `->`

```
for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
  printf("name: %s, age:%i\n", p[i]->names, p[i]->ages);
}
```

And as you increment `i` in your for loop, you dont need to move your p[i] pointer, remove, `p[i] = p[i + 1]`

```
for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
  insert (&p[i], names[i], ages[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`person *p[7]` declare an array of seven pointers to `person`, so `p[i]` is a pointer to structure. Therefore, you need to dereference this pointer to access to its members.

```
printf("name: %s, age:%i\n", (*p[i]).names, (*p[i]).ages);
```

To improve readability, you can use the postfix operator `->`.

```
printf("name: %s, age:%i\n", p[i]->names, p[i]->ages);
```

> **C11 (1570), § 6.5.2.3 Structure and union members**
>   A postfix expression followed by the `->` operator and an identifier
>   designates a member    of a structure or union object. The value is
>   that of the named member of the object to   which the first expression
>   points, and is an lvalue) If the first expression is a pointer to
>        a qualified type, the result has the so-qualified version of the type of the designated
>           member.